# Cannot import a node module inside a module web worker on the browser

Tags: javascript, node-modules, web-worker, worker

1- I am trying to import a node module into my worker. I could not find a way to get it done in a straightforward manner. Many people were suggesting using things like webpack or external libraries. Why can't I simply import the node module like a regular js module import like so?

```js
import blazeface from '@tensorflow-models/blazeface';
```

meanwhile, I can import other modules I created like

```js
import getDetectedFace from "./detectFace.js";
```

2. When this error occurs I do not see any output to the console that an error has occurred. I can only tell because my worker does nothing when I try this type of import. Is this normal?

Comment: Hi, did you find answer for this? thanks

Comment: @Cam I could not find a solution unfortunately